# An argument that accepts any kind of Types (like: boolean, string, float.. etc)

Tags: delphi, type-kinds

i have this code here:

```
type  // This Enumerator Type for Handling the Registry Results ...
 TRegistryKind = (rkBOOL, rkSTRING, rkEXPANDSTR, rkINTEGER, rkFLOAT, rkCURRENCY, rkBINARY_DATA, rkDATE, rkTIME, rkDATE_TIME);

 TRegistryKindResult = record
   AsBool: Boolean;
   AsString: string;
   AsInteger: Integer;
   AsFloat: Single;
   AsCurrency: Currency;
 end;
```

what i need here is to create a single procedure with universal pram that accept any kind of input Types and save them to registry ..
here is the trick:

```
procedure TAppSettings.Save_Setting_ToRegistry(AKey, AItem_Setting: String;
    AValue: **UnknownType**; ARegKind: TRegistryKind);
var
  Reg: TRegIniFile;
begin
  Reg := TRegIniFile.Create(AKey);
  try
    case ARegKind of
      rkBOOL: Reg.WriteBool('', AItem_Setting, AValue);
      rkSTRING: Reg.WriteString('', AItem_Setting, AValue);
    end;

    Reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

what should i do for the param **AValue** ? is there a smart way that can tell my Delphi IDE to accept any input  from the 5 kinds that i defined in **TRegistryKindResult** record above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old-school approach is to use [variants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)). Then, in fact, you don't even need the `TRegistryKind` parameter:

```pascal
procedure SaveSetting(const AKey, ASetting: string; AValue: Variant);
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
begin
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    if Reg.OpenKey(AKey, True) then
    begin
      case VarType(AValue) of
        varSmallint, varInteger, varShortInt, varByte, varWord:
          Reg.WriteInteger(ASetting, AValue);
        varCurrency:
          Reg.WriteCurrency(ASetting, AValue);
        varSingle, varDouble:
          Reg.WriteFloat(ASetting, AValue);
        varBoolean:
          Reg.WriteBool(ASetting, AValue);
        varString, varUString:
          Reg.WriteString(ASetting, AValue);
      else
        raise Exception.Create('Unsupported variant type.');
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To test it:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SaveSetting('Software\Rejbrand\Test', 'intsetting', 123);
  SaveSetting('Software\Rejbrand\Test', 'cursetting', Currency(3.1415));
  SaveSetting('Software\Rejbrand\Test', 'fltsetting', Double(3.1415));
  SaveSetting('Software\Rejbrand\Test', 'boolsetting', True);
  SaveSetting('Software\Rejbrand\Test', 'strsetting', 'Hello, World!');
end;
```

Comment: Regarding the "you don't even need the TRegistryKind parameter": How would you handle rkEXPANDSTR?

Comment: @UweRaabe: Yes, then you can use an additional parameter. By in most cases, you don't need that. (For instance, you could have a `AExpandStr: Boolean = False` final parameter, so you don't have to specify it in the 99% of the time when you don't need it.)

Comment: can someone help to choose the best Answer HhHh (i'm so confused between all Good Answers... and ofcourse the Respectable Answers Owners)

Comment: @Roberto: Choose the answer that works best for you. Remy and I both use the old-school `Variant` data type. While Remy uses it directly in your scenario, I also point out that you can skip the "registry kind" parameter. Uwe, on the other hand, bases his answer on the new `TValue` type. Antonio uses a trick, but it doesn't work with non-variable parameters and it sacrifices type-safety.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  i will choose your answer as best (not for that it works best for me but for your second answer here) and All Answers are works best for me except ontonio (still i can't understand it) I wish there was a multiple evaluation so I pick you all (like variant or TValue does HhHhHh) thank you All and best regards...

Answer (score 2):

Unit *System.RTTI* provides the type `TValue` for that.

```
procedure TAppSettings.Save_Setting_ToRegistry(AKey, AItem_Setting: string; AValue: TValue; ARegKind: TRegistryKind);
var
  Reg: TRegIniFile;
begin
  Reg := TRegIniFile.Create(AKey);
  try
    case ARegKind of
      rkBOOL:
        Reg.WriteBool('', AItem_Setting, AValue.AsBoolean);
      rkSTRING:
        Reg.WriteString('', AItem_Setting, AValue.AsString);
    end;

    Reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Variant`:

```pascal
procedure TAppSettings.Save_Setting_ToRegistry(AKey, AItem_Setting: String;
  AValue: Variant; ARegKind: TRegistryKind);
var
  Reg: TRegIniFile;
begin
  Reg := TRegIniFile.Create(AKey);
  try
    case ARegKind of
      rkBOOL: Reg.WriteBool('', AItem_Setting, AValue);
      rkSTRING: Reg.WriteString('', AItem_Setting, AValue);
      ...
    end;
    Reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (used in the past, but not tested now):

```pascal
procedure TAppSettings.Save_Setting_ToRegistry(AKey, AItem_Setting: String;
    const AValue; ARegKind: TRegistryKind);
var
  Reg: TRegIniFile;
  VBool: Boolean absolute AValue;
  VString: String absolute AValue;
  VInteger: Integer absolute AValue;
  VFloat: Single absolute AValue;
  VCurrency: Currency absolute AValue;
begin
  Reg := TRegIniFile.Create(AKey);
  try
    case ARegKind of
      rkBOOL: Reg.WriteBool('', AItem_Setting, VBool);
      rkSTRING: Reg.WriteString('', AItem_Setting, VString);
      // Manage the other types...
    end;

    Reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i use this:
Save_Setting_ToRegistry(APP_Settings_Key, FSelectedSetting, 'test', rkSTRING);
but it says: Incompatible types: 'TRegistryKind' and 'string'

Comment: I bet you made a typo between AValue and ARegKind - there is a semicolon, not a comma.

Comment: @StefanGlienke yes correct (now i learn 3 super solutions ) and sorry Mr: Antonio (now i can understand your super solution) Thank you All (and sorry for my bad english HhHh)